# Updating database with jquery ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I try to update a database field when user clicks or leaves an input field.
For that I'm using jquery `$.post` function.
This is my jquery function:

```
 $('.ajadd').click(function(){ //.ajadd is the class of the input field
        var dbfield=addtitle;
        var fieldval='check';

        var post_txt='additional.php?dbfield='+dbfield+'&fieldval='+fieldval;

        $.post(post_txt,function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

And I process the request in the `additional.php` file like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['fieldval'])){

    $fieldname=$_POST['dbfield'];
    $fieldvalue=$_POST['fieldval'];
    $a=new mysqli('localhost','root','','mydbname');
    $query="UPDATE mydbtable SET $fieldname=' $fieldvalue' WHERE id=1";
    $res=$a->query($query);
    echo 'update complete';
}
```

I simplified the code so you can come to the point where the problem is. I know that I didn't process the `$_POST` array for SQL injections and that's not what I want now. I just want to know why this code isn't working.

Additional point:  I checked the database connection and it's working fine.
I checked the query outside the if statement and it's working. 
In my php file I echoed out 'update complete' and in my $.post callback function I alerted the return data but it's showing an empty messagebox.
What this means to me is that the php file was executed successfully but I don't know why I'm ending up with an empty callback functions messagebox.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $('.ajadd').change(function(){ //use change instead of click
        var dbfield=addtitle;
        var fieldval='check';

        var post_txt='additional.php';
// you also need to pass data separately instead of query string
        $.post(post_txt, { dbfield : dbfield , fieldval : fieldval} ,function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending it as `GET` and not `POST`. So change your code this way:

```
var post_txt = 'additional.php';

$.post(post_txt, {
  'dbfield':  dbfield,
  'fieldval': fieldval
}, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Now the data would be sent as `POST` and not `GET`.

Comment: When you use $.post, the parameters are sent via $_POST and not $_GET. I checked the net tab in firebug and it says that there is a post request with the keys of dbfield and fieldval and the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you are doing wrong according to me,

Firstly,Using click event for a textbox, instead you are looking for `focusout` i guess.Use it like..

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
    //CODE HERE
});
```

And in the ajax,you are sending data in url paramters and accessing using POST.Change it to get.

Comment: When you use $.post, the parameters are sent via $_POST and not $_GET. I checked the net tab in firebug and it says that there is a post request with the keys of dbfield and fieldval and the corresponding values.  Also the event doesn't matter at this point because even the focusout() event doesn't work.